# How to get only one field instead of list in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So, there I have request that return one or two fields depends on their existence in document. But I need to receive only one field (no matter which one). How can I do it?

```
 {
  "_source" : ["yearOfBirth", "fullBirthDate"],
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "yearOfBirth": {
                        "gte": "1900",
                        "lte": "2020"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "fullBirthDate": {
                        "gte": "1900",
                        "lte": "2020"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean some document have both, some has one of them, and some have none?

Comment: exactly, fullBirthDate is new field, that will replace yearOfBirth in future, but now we have problem: fullBirthDate is better format for understanding ages of users, and if it presets, we prefer to use fullBirthDate rather than yearOfBirth